# Accessibility tools for SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, accessibility

I have a requirement where I need to create a site which addresses all the `WCAG standards`. Please suggest some tools for the same.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is compliant with WCAG standards as mentioned on Microsoft's site here:

https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Get-ready-Build-an-accessible-SharePoint-site-3A1DF3AD-F093-450C-85A6-B3BF70FD6ABB

Although the content from SharePoint is compliant with WCAG, you don't guarantee the users' content would be compliant or not, for that, you need to follow some practices, like in this article:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Accessibility-features-in-SharePoint-Online-f291404a-dc7e-44de-a31f-d81b3099c2b9?CorrelationId=ee3d6b92-b458-4c76-81b4-f79fcc40fc99&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

I suggest to read more about it in the discussion here:

http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/is-sharepoint-2013-aa-or-a-wcag-compliance

Comment: Could you provide me some reference to other tools that I can use for this?

Comment: Mancy, What do you mean by tools here? You have to follow guidelines and recommendations while creating content and designing your SharePoint pages, it's not about tools.

Comment: Total Validator is one such tool that helps us to know WCAG issues in a website. Do have an idea about any such tools that are specially used for SharePoint accessibility issues?

Comment: For SharePoint, no. Just the guidelines from Microsoft.